# Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'generation-ii'... in Ionic-Angular

Tags: json, angular, api, ionic4

I'm trying to retrieve a list of species according to its category(generation), but I can't get the **name** property of pokemon_species as shown below.
[image]

I only get this error whenever I run my code and select a particular category(generation):
[image]

I don't know where I went wrong or what's the proper format for accessing the array names and outputting it in my view.

Here's my html code:

```
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select</ion-label>
    <ion-select
      [(ngModel)]="generationSelected"
      (ngModelChange)="onGenerationSelected($event)"
    >
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let species of generation" [value]="species.id"
        >Generation {{ species.id }}</ion-select-option
      >
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

 <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label> Generation {{generationSelected}} </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let s of species" class="ion-text-capitalize">
      <ion-label slot="start"><b>{{ s.pokemon_species.name }}:</b></ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

And here's my typescript:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loadGenerationSpecies();
    this.generationSelected = 1;
  }

  onGenerationSelected(val: any) {
    this.customFunction(val);
  }

  customFunction(val: any) {
    let id = val;
    this.pokeService.getGenerationSpecies(val).subscribe((details) => {
      this.species = details;
      console.log("getGenerationSpecies:", this.species);
    });
  }
  loadGenerationSpecies(loadMore = false, event?) {
    if (loadMore) {
      this.offset += 7;
    }

    this.pokeService.getGeneration(this.offset).subscribe((res) => {
      this.generation = [...this.generation, ...res];

    });
  }
```

Here's my service.ts for getGenerationSpecies:

```
  getGenerationSpecies(index) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/generation/${index}`).pipe(
      map((species) => {
        let pokemonSpecies = Object.keys(species["pokemon_species"]);
        species["id"] = pokemonSpecies
          .map((speciesKey) => species["pokemon_species"][speciesKey])
          .filter((id) => id);
        console.log("species:", species);
        return species;
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: you are iterating over something that is not an Array. for exemple I don't know if it's this part exactly but, you assign `this.species = details;` (details beeing an object) and then do `*ngFor="let s of species"`

Comment: Hi, is it possible to get the pokemon_species array with the name property from the details object? I can already retrieve the object with that array from the console, I just don't know how to output the values of the particular array.

Comment: yes it is possible, but is quite hard to debug without an exemple. My guess from what I see is that you should do *ngFor="let s of species.pokemon_species"

`let s of species`